# How do you get the name of the current virtual directory using ASP Classic?

Tags: asp-classic, virtual-directory

How do you get the name of the current virtual directory using ASP Classic? In ASP.NET you can use `Request.ApplicationPath` to find this.

For example, let's say you have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/virtual_directory/subdirectory/file.asp
```

In ASP.NET, `Request.ApplicationPath` would return **/virtual_directory**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the virtual path to the file from one of several server variables - try either:

- `Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")`
- `Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")`

(but not `INSTANCE_META_PATH` as previously suggested - this gives you the meta base path, not the virtual path you're expecting).

Either server variable will give you the virtual path including any sub-directories and the file name - given your example, you'll get "/virtual_directory/subdirectory/file.asp". If you just want the virtual directory, you'll need to strip off everything after the second forward slash using whatever method you prefer for plucking a directory out of a path, such as:

```
s = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
i = InStr(2, s, "/")
If i > 0 Then
    s = Left(s, i - 1)
End If
```

or:

```
s = "/" & Split(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"), "/")(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using: Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")

or try using Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH") if that does not work for you.

For a list of other server variables try this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp