# Javascript Path Defining

Tags: javascript

I have two servers where I want to use one script file. One location has URL http://localhost:8080/one/simple/ and the other location is http://localhost:8181. Now I have one html file hosted on both the servers where in order to use that script file I have included it like

```
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

Now this code works fine on http://localhost:8181, but not on http://localhost:8080/one/simple/, console throws an error that the file is not available.

What's the correct way to write the path so that it can work on both the servers?

Comment: Well, you should check if the file is really available on http:/localhost:8080/one/simple/

Comment: Does it need changing to `<script src="script.js"></script>`?

Comment: Is the source directory of both servers the same root directory of files?

Comment: What you point to in your html is this: http://localhost:8080/script.js and http://localhost:8181/script.js

Comment: <script src="script.js"></script> this code works fine with root HTML page, what if I have an iframe in that HTML page which also needs to include this script. With the above code it generates the complete path of HTML file where file exists.

Comment: Well if you are using ASP.Net or other server side technology, you can try spitting complete path to script containing any virtual directories etc.

Comment: I am using PHP, so any code to get that path? When in iframe src i use <script src="script.js"></script> the browser changes it to folder1/js/script.js as iframe's HTML file is under folder1/js/. Any way to get rid of folder1/js/ part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try following:

```
<script src='<?Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")?>/script.js'></script>
```

as suggested in answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470987/how-do-you-get-the-name-of-the-current-virtual-directory-using-asp-classic) question.

It is supposed to give you virtual path.